# Framework code is exposed when app crashes - iOS

Tags: ios, ios8, frameworks

We have developed a framework targeting iOS 8+ devices using iOS's new creating frameworks feature. However, whenever the app crashes within the framework, the implementation detail is exposed to the developer who is using the framework which defeats its inherent purpose of hiding a class' implementation.

Is there any specific reason for this behaviour? Or is this just a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code inside the framework is shown because XCode has access to the framework path from your machine. 
If you try running your app from a place/machine which does not have access to your framework, you will not see this happening.
So don't worry, your framework's code will not be exposed to your clients.